# Getting CakePHP HtmlHelper to generate a "date" input

Tags: php, html, forms, cakephp

I've been making some basic CRUD pages for my cakePHP app using the HtmlHelper for the views. This is handy for building forms but for date inputs the helper by default generates 3 select boxes for the date which is quite cumbersome to use.

HTML5 introduces the `input[type=date]` and most browsers now incorporate some nice native interfaces to deal with it; e.g. Chrome produces a nice date-picker for date inputs.

I know it is possible to make the HtmlHelper just make the input a `text` box instead of the 3 dropdown by doing the following:

```
echo $this->Form->input('my_date', array('type' => 'text'));
```

But when I do

```
echo $this->Form->input('my_date', array('type' => 'date'));
```

it ignores the 2nd arguement and goes back to the 3 selects.

Is there a way to get the helper to make a date input?

Comment: The problem there is that `date` is [an internal type](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L1052) that generates 3 selects. `$this->Form->date('my_date')` probably works, but will not generate the wrapper div/error message

Comment: If I ommit the 2nd argument as you suggested it still generates the 3 selects as it seems Cake figures out which input type to generate by the field datatype from the database.

Comment: The form helper is a hairy beast - unfortunately the problem you're hitting can't be addressed in the core without breaking BC compatibility. I recommend cheating (use your own helper/write the markup by hand/generate a text input and str-replace the type) =).

Comment: What about a jquery solution to hide the 3 selects, generate a new date input and populate the selects just prior to submit - or will this be clunky and unreliable?

Comment: Or maybe just generate a text input and use jquery to change the type to date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seem the HtmlHelper has not yet evolved to make use of the "date" input.

If you tell the helper to generate the date input as a text field, adding a jQuery one-liner can convert it to a date input.

So:

```
echo $this->Form->input('my_date', array('type' => 'text'));
```

to generate the field. Then:

```
$('#idOfMyDate').attr('type', 'date');
```

To change it to a date input.

If anyone has a better way I'd be keen to hear it.

Comment: No JS: `$this->Form->text('my_date', array('type' => 'date'))`. However this will only generate an `input` element, ie no `div`, no `label`, no error message, you'd need to create those separately.

Comment: It seems much cleaner just to use 1 line of JS to change the input type rather than manually generate all the extra form elements.

Comment: Expanding on the above you could also do:
`echo '<div class="input text">' . $this->Form->label('date_of_birth') . $this->Form->date('date_of_birth') . '</div>';`

Answer (score 3):

The CakePHP FormHelper uses Widgets to render different input types. For "datetime" types, it uses the DateTimeWidget per default.

To get a regular input with the attribute `type="date"`, you just have to tell CakePHP which widget to use.

In the View (usually App\AppView.php), you can configure the FormHelper:

```
<?php

namespace App\View;

use Cake\View\View;

class AppView extends View
{
    public function initialize() {
        $this->loadHelper('Form', [
            'widgets' => [
                'datetime' => ['Basic'],
            ],
        ]);
    }
}

?>
```

The BasicWidget is the most basic widget which is used to render regular text inputs.

Then, in your view, you can just use `'type' => 'date'` as expected:

```
echo $this->Form->input('my_date', array('type' => 'date'));
```

Or, since CakePHP already sets the type to "date" since the database column is a datetime field you can just leave it like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('my_date');
```

The result is a regular text input with `type="date"`.

---

For future readers: In the most recent version of CakePHP, you would use the method `Form::control` instead of `Form::input`. Everything else still applies.

Comment: I believe this is the most correct way to do this. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    echo $this->Form->text('my_date',array('type' => 'date');
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this it'll work as a charm

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="Description"><?php echo __('Date'); ?></label>
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('scheduled_date', array('label'=> false, 'div' => false, 'class'=>'form-control', 'type' => 'text')); ?>
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Some explanation:

- 'div' => false: it's necessary to desable the div rendered by input() FormHelper function
- 'label' => false: it's necessary to desable the label rendered by input() FormHelper function

Take a look at [cake PHP form helper doc](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with jquery

PHP

```
<?= $this->Form->control('birth_date', ['value' => $birth_date->i18nFormat('yyyy-MM-dd'), 'type' => 'text']); ?>
```

JS

```
$('#birth-date').attr('type', 'date');
```

Answer (score -1):

It's obvious that Cake's FormHelper is messing up with `<input type "date">`. Therefore I solved this problem the following way (in CakePHP 2.x)

- Copy `FormHelper.php` from `lib\Cake\View\Helper\`
- Paste it to `app\View\Helper`. Now Cake will use *your* Form Helper instead of its own.
- Open the new `FormHelper.php`, go to `protected function _getInput($args) {`, search for `case 'date':` and change it from:

  ```
  case 'date':
      $options += array('value' => $selected);
      return $this->dateTime($fieldName, $dateFormat, null, $options);
  ```

  to:

  ```
  case 'date':
      return $this->{$type}($fieldName, $options);
  ```

Cake will now stop transforming `<input type="date">` into select boxes.

Keep in mind that with every future release of Cake 2.x you will have to transfer possible changes in Cake's Form Helper into your own Form Helper manually.